# NodeJs send you need to enable javascript on certain request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have a Nodejs API that sends responses to a react application.

When I send a request for user information on login, the request succeeds and I get back a proper response. The thing is after I sent an initial request to log in, I get back the this response.

```
You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
```

This only happens in production. Locally it's fine. Even doing a production build locally works just fine. It's only when I deploy to my AWS containers.

Here is my API package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-api",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon ./bin/www",
    "prod": "sudo forever stopall && forever start ./bin/www",
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "seed": "node ./setup/seed.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 12.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.738.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "bluebird": "^3.7.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "braintree": "^3.5.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "connect-pg-simple": "^6.2.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "file-type": "^14.7.1",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "multiparty": "^4.2.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.2",
    "nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "pg": "^8.2.1",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.3",
    "pg-transaction": "^1.0.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "winston": "^3.3.3"
  }
}
```

Here is my application API.

```
const httpProxy = require("http-proxy");
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");

const appConfig = require("./config");
const appPath = `./app.${appConfig.isProduction ? "prod" : "dev"}`;

const logger = require("./utils/logger");
const app = require(appPath);

const apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

const ACUTAL_API = process.env.ACTUAL_API || "http://localhost:8181";

app.set("x-powered-by", false);

app.all("/api/*", function (req, res) {
  logger.info("reverse proxying to api");
  console.log("reverse proxying");
  apiProxy.web(req, res, { target: ACTUAL_API });
});

if (!appConfig.isProduction) {
  app.listen(appConfig.port, () => {
    logger.info(`Server started at: http://localhost:${appConfig.port}`);
  });
} else {
  https
    .createServer(
      {
        /* Certificate Managed By AWS ACM */
        key: fs.readFileSync("./certificates/localhost.key"),
        cert: fs.readFileSync("./certificates/localhost.crt"),
        passphrase: "",
      },
      app
    )
    .listen(appConfig.port);
}
```

Application API app.prod.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");

const BUILD_DIR = path.join(__dirname, "../build/");
console.log(BUILD_DIR);
app.use(express.static(BUILD_DIR));

const HTML_FILE = path.join(BUILD_DIR, "index.html");

app.get("*", (req, res) => res.sendFile(HTML_FILE));

module.exports = app;
```

Application API Package.json

```
{
  "name": "proxy-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "proxy server for web",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "YoMommasKrypton",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-http-proxy": "^1.6.2",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "node-env-file": "^0.1.8",
    "winston": "2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems likely that your server code is using some sort of middleware or other infrastructure that causes this.  Not much we can do (other than wild guesses) without seeing  your code.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, it is. I'll update

Comment: Are you hosting your react application inside of your api? You are showing 02 packages.json and I don't see the react dependencies. If the message "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app." in on the browser, the problem is with the react build. #1 Are you open to a distributed solution? #2 Share us how are you building the app

Comment: Yes, I have 3 package.jsons. 
I have the application package.json that sits as a sibling to a server directory. That’s the package JSON that holds all the references to the packages that build the application. 
In the server directory I have a package.json that is responsible for all the packages that deal specifically with serving the application for production. And the package.json that deals particularly with the API.

Comment: I should mention that locally, Even running the production server, everything is fine. It’s only when deployed to containers and running on port 443 is where I have issues.